# Using Regexp in MySQL. Will it give an occurrence count?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a VARCHAR (InnoDB table) and I want to count how many instances of the a string in the form of [###] or [##a-f] there may be in the field in each row (Using the representation '#' to indicate that the placeholder for an integer, and a-f to signify that a single letter in the range from a to f may be preent.)
the regex

```
\[[0-9]+\]|\[[0-9]+[a-k]\]
```

returns 1 if it finds a match, but I have not yet found info mentioning whether it is possible to have the regex return an occurrence count for matches within each record. Is that possible?

Ideally I'd like the results:

```
objid  |   text   | item_count
-------------------------------
  1       <blah>      7
  2       <blah>      2
  3       <blah>      1
  4       <blah>      0
  5       <blah>      10
```

I have no idea what the limits or constraints of regex in MySQL might be in this regard.
If it can only be accomplished programmatically, I'd prefer to use a stored procedure. Keep it in the database context.

Please note that my question is not simply about solving the problem, it is particularly about the use of regex.

I am curious about what other database-oriented solutions there might be as well, but I'm very curioius about what I am asking regexp to do here.

Comment: Could you just count occurrences of `'[99'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that the regexp function in mysql is merely for identifying selectable rows, based on a different parameter data than "where" or "like".

I'll have to use a perl script to accomplish the task at hand: How many occurrences in the field of some string that looks like [[0-9]+]|[[0-9]+[a-k]]?

By the way a very awesome web tool I found during my searches, Regex Tester: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not offer the functionality you are looking for.  My first comment is that your column seems to contain a list of codes in a string.  This is a bad data design.  You should have an association/junction table for this.

There is a way to count occurrences of fixed strings in another string, using `replace()`.  MySQL does not offer `regex_replace()` (although you can probably google and find code for a version for MySQL).  Your codes are pretty simply, so with a rather inelegant formulation, you can solve the problem.  The following counts the number of `'[999]'` in the string:

```
select (length(replace(col, '[999]', '[999]a')) - length(col))
```

You can just repeat this for the n codes:

```
select ((length(replace(col, '[999]', '[999]a')) - length(col)) +
        (length(replace(col, '[99a]', '[99a]a')) - length(col)) +
        . . . 
        (length(replace(col, '[99f]', '[99f]a')) - length(col))
       ) as numcodes
```

If you know each code appears at most one time, you can replace this with a somewhat simpler comparison:

```
select (col like '%[999]%' +
        col like '%[99a]%' +
        . . .
        col like '%[99f]%'
       )
```

Let me stress again that storing codes as a list in a column is a bad idea.  If your column is doing this, you should create an association table, which would make it much easier to do this particular query.

Comment: 999 is just a representation for numbers.
these are text strings and contain forms of string that look like [1] up to [100], and in a non-uniform way is interspersed with forms like [1a], [7a], [2a], [2b] -> [2d].